# Base command line for builds in Maven

Tags: maven, anypoint-studio

I am using apache maven version 3.5.0 in Eclipse. I have problem with this error - "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:eclipse". I guess it makes by wrong command in Preferences->Anypoint Studio->Maven->Base command line for builds. Now, I have command - "mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help documentation on how to ask a good question, and also look up how to properly layout your question. As it stands it is difficult to read and understand.

Comment: You should post more information about the error you are getting. There is probably some more text that is part of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven-eclipse-plugin is deprecated and should not be used. Actually, it can destroy your project.

Newer Eclipse versions (like Mars, Neon, Oxygen) have m2e included, which does all the Maven-Eclipse magic for you.